# "Text is Undefined" error using Markdown?

Tags: javascript, markdown

I downloaded markdown from http://code.google.com/p/wmd/ (well, in fact I cloned the `hg` repository), in order to have a client-side highlighter for static text, i.e. I don't need the editor.

However, I tried to instantiate the converter, essentially like in the [demo:](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var conv = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var ed = new Markdown.Editor(conv);
    ed.run();
  })();
  </script>
```

However, if I run this, the JS error console tells me:

```
Error: text is undefined
Source File: http://bitmask.de/markdown_test/Markdown.Converter.js
Line: 149
```

Which I traced to the call of `ed.run()`.

I put the whole minimal demo on http://bitmask.de/markdown_test/js.html

I didn't modify the js files or anything (basically because I have very very limited js knowledge), just did what the demo does. What's wrong here?

Comment: Well, don't you have to assign the result of `ed.run()` somewhere?  Also, what is `conv` actually processing?  You haven't assigned your input element to it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well, have a look at the linked demo, please. It does the same thing (end of the page) and my browser displays *that* correctly.

Comment: Heh.  It's too bad the [documentation website](http://wmd-editor.com/) is down. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `<div>` element for the input, it has to be something editable (e.g. `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`):

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
  <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
  <textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input">`hello` *cruel* world</textarea>
</div>
```

Be also carefull about spaces in the HTML source. Your second sample has a line starting with more than four spaces, which means "code" in Markdown:

```
  <!-- this will be formated as <pre> element -->
  <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input">
  `hello` *cruel* world
  </textarea>
```

Comment: Although it doesn't crash any more with a `textarea` the result isn't rendered properly: http://bitmask.de/markdown_test/js2.html

Comment: @bitmask It is because your input begins with 4 spaces (check the HTML source), which means "do not format this text" in Markdown. So your result is in fact rendered correctly.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš: Ah! how stupid of me. That sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, to get this to work, you have to assign the `wmd-panel` css class to the HTML element that you want the WMD Markdown to act on.

The Google Code demo looks like this:

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>PageDown Demo Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wmd-panel">
            <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input"> This is the *first* editor.
------------------------------

Just plain **Markdown**, except that the input is sanitized:

<marquee>I'm the ghost from the past!</marquee> </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>

        <br /> <br />

        <div class="wmd-panel">
            <div id="wmd-button-bar-second"></div>
            <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-second"> This is the *second* editor.
------------------------------

It has a plugin hook registered that surrounds all words starting with the letter A with asterisks before doing the Markdown conversion. Another one gives bare links a nicer link text. User input isn't sanitized here:

<marquee>I'm the ghost from the past!</marquee>

http://google.com

http://stackoverflow.com

It also includes a help button. </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="wmd-preview-second" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
        var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
        editor1.run();

        var converter2 = new Markdown.Converter();

        converter2.hooks.chain("preConversion", function (text) {
            return text.replace(/\b(a\w*)/gi, "*$1*");
        });

        converter2.hooks.chain("plainLinkText", function (url) {
            return "This is a link to " + url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, "");
        });

        var help = function () { alert("Do you need help?"); }

        var editor2 = new Markdown.Editor(converter2, "-second", { handler: help });

        editor2.run();
    })();

</script>
```

Notice the use of `class="wmd-panel"` to mark those areas that the WMD Markdown  is to act on?

Comment: Well, I figured the `converter2` and `editor2` were separate from what I use. So really I understand this as two separate demos. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You have to assign something to the converter, or nothing happens.  Yeah, I don't quite understand it either... I'm still looking at the code.

Comment: OK, have a look at my edit.  You most likely have to tell Markdown which areas you want it to act on by marking them with CSS classes.